# Discord on Ready tree sync with Javascript

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have been trying to write new bot on my own looking at different projects which are written in python. Since they are written in python I have no clue how to migrate them to javascript therefore I am searching through documentation. Yet, I couldn't find anything like `tree`or `CommandTree`anywhere in those documentations. I use discord.js .

#### Python Code:

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
tree = app_commands.CommandTree(client)
```

#### My code in on ready:

```js
client.on('ready', async () => {
    await client.user.setActivity({ type: 'WATCHING', name: loadConfigs.activity_name });

    if (!fs.existsSync(`${process.env.DATA_PATH}tracked_accounts.db`)) {
        initDB();
    }

    // TODO: Handle tree.on_error and load cogs

    log.info(`${client.user.tag} is online`);

    const slashCommands = **await client.tree.sync(); //?!?!??**
    log.info(`Synced ${slashCommands.length} slash commands`);
});
```

Basically, what is the equivalent of python code to javascript in here. I want to sync slash commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

discord.js does not treat command is this sort of way, it is up to the user to deal with how they are loaded and how the events are listened to.

I would recommend looking through this guide, which shows how to implement commands:
https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/slash-commands.html